# R simple Bootstrap

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I have a data frame (Applications) with two columns

```
Customer    Application
1           1
1           0
1           0
1           1
1           1
1           0
1           1
1           0
1           0
1           1
1           1
```

Where the application rate is

```
sum(Applications$Application)/sum(Applications$Customer).
```

I've been asked to bootstrap this application rate by taking running 1000 samples of 1000 customers to get distribution and confidence level for the application rate. I tried using the `boot` package as follows

```
f2 <- function(Loan,Customer){sum(Applications$Application)/sum(Applications$Customer)}
bootapp1 <-(boot(Applications, f2, 1000))
bootapp1

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = Bootstrap_Test, statistic = f2, R = 1000)


Bootstrap Statistics :
       original  bias    std. error
t1* 0.003052608       0           0
```

Obviously this isn't what I'm looking for as it doesn't give any bias or standard error.

Would anyone be able to tell me a quick way of getting the results I need. I imagine there must be a really simple way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to tweak your function, which needs two arguments. From the help file on `boot`, under the argument `statistic`:

> A function which when applied to data returns a vector containing the statistic(s) of interest. When sim = "parametric", the first argument to statistic must be the data. For each replicate a simulated dataset returned by ran.gen will be passed. In all other cases statistic must take at least two arguments. The first argument passed will always be the original data. The second will be a vector of indices, frequencies or weights which define the bootstrap sample.

```
library(boot)
x <- structure(list(Customer = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                 1L, 1L), Application = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                          1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Customer", "Application"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                               -11L))
f2 <- function(x, index){sum(x[index, "Application"])/sum(x[index, "Customer"])}
bootapp1 <- boot(data = x, statistic = f2, R = 1000)
> bootapp1

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
  boot(data = x, statistic = f2, R = 1000)


Bootstrap Statistics :
  original       bias    std. error
t1* 0.5454545 0.0005454545     0.14995
```